# How to change window location hash on mouse scroll and arrow up and down key?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to change windows.location.hash on mouse wheel and arrow key press. Some of my code I have mentioned bellow.
Id changing on mouse cursor click but its not working on mouse wheel or arrow key.
In my HTML every class="section" have full screen and home are first screen and it is bellow most screen and above about after services and top most contact.

```js
$(function() {
    if (window.location.hash) {
        window.location.hash;
    } else {
        window.location.hash = '#home';
    };
});
```

```css
.containerBox>div {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}

.containerBox>div:target {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fullpage" class="containerBox">
    <div class="section" id="home"></div>
    <div class="section" id="about"></div>
    <div class="section" id="services"></div>
    <div class="section" id="contact"></div>
</div>
```

I have try so many script. but it doesn't work
Please help
thanks